# Want to store in Redis via Node.js

Tags: json, node.js, redis, key-value-store

I want to store a hash/JSON data of users in [Redis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis_%28data_store%29) and want to add the user in users hash the user data like this.

For example, `users = {}`;

When user *rahul* logs in then `users` will become.

```
users = {
    rahul: {
        username: 'rahul',          
    }
}
```

And when user *namita* login then

```
users = {
    rahul: {
        username: 'rahul',

    },
    namita: {
        username: 'namita',

    }
}
```

What will the code be to do this in Redis?

How will I initialise the key `users` and add *rahul* to it?

Out of this set, hset, etc., which function do I need to use?

And how will I retrieve the data of `users['rahul']` via Redis?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Probably the most optimal solution to store single hash/json would be to use [hashes](http://redis.io/commands#hash) commands. I also had this "[dilemma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252456/storing-object-properties-in-redis/5253519#5253519)" and there are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701491/save-nested-hash-in-redis-via-a-node-js-app) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729891/redis-performance-store-json-object-as-a-string) regarding data structure containing users with JSON-like objects in Redis.

**EDIT**

Use [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) module. It's actively maintained by a pro a probably the most used node.js driver for Redis. First you should use [SADD](http://redis.io/commands/sadd) command to add your new JSON object name into the set in order to track which items "users" contain. Then use [HMSET](http://redis.io/commands/hmset) to store "user:rahul" object key-value hashes. Example:

```
// add first user
client.sadd("users", "user:rahul");
client.hmset("user:rahul", "username", "rahul", "foo", "bar");

// add second user
client.sadd("users", "user:namita");
client.hmset("user:namita", "username", "namita", "foo", "baz");
```

You can now access your users by various types of redis [hash](http://redis.io/commands#hash) command depending if you want to retrieve only certain hash values or the entire single user object. To get all of the users you can use [SMEMBERS](http://redis.io/commands/smembers) command for example. Try to look at the node_redis [readme](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/blob/master/README.md) and [examples](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/tree/master/examples) where you should find more information about its API.

Comment: please write the sample code , i had gone through the question these suggest after the users but first how to declare the users hash ? or am planning to use redissql is it good ?