# How do I prevent an ObjectID from becoming primitive?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

How do I prevent an ObjectID form becoming primitive when passing in and out of Redis?

Parsing to JSON string? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "prevent an ObjectID form becoming primitive"?

Comment: Redis converts all objects to primitive strings and ints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either store your object as JSON string representation in simple [string](http://redis.io/commands#string) or use [hash](http://redis.io/commands#hash) data structure. Node.js [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) module offers friendlier hash commands which may be useful. There is also a library for storing objects in redis called [nohm](https://github.com/maritz/nohm) which is based on object-hash mapping library [ohm](http://ohm.keyvalue.org/).

Comment: Using JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse() I don't think a hash structure helps here but maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: @fancy: Try to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252456/storing-object-properties-in-redis) question and answer. Maybe it will help you.

Comment: yea, I use hashes like that. I still need to stringify and parse things to have them return as proper objects outside of redis.